# Marking multiple different location in Map View?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm a newbie in android. All I can do is to put a marker in the user current location.
But what I need to do is put a marker in the user current location and to a specific places that near the user location. For an example a marker in the user and a marker in all the KFC that near the user location. But I don't have any idea yet how to make this work.

any thoughts will be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you might need to do is an annotation, or itemizedOverlay. This is covered in Part 2 of this tutorial, which is step by step.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

Otherwise if you are just firing an intent to the map app. Then just sending the location of KFC would suffice since the user location will appear in the native app anyway

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

geo:latitude,longitude
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=business+near+city

Comment: but how can I do search the near KFC with out using intent. I'm not using intent I'm using Geo.

Comment: Do you want an API that can search for places of business? Google Places API can do that.